# Regex Specific Search lines in any order and may or may not exist

Tags: c#, regex, string, irc

Straight to the point. I am working on an IRC bot, and I am at a brick wall I have been pounding my head on since 4am this morning.

I am trying to sort The IRC Raw 005 (IS_SUPPORTED) strings specifically in regex groups. An example string looks like this.

```
Nickname MAXTARGETS=20 WALLCHOPS WATCH=128 WATCHOPTS=A SILENCE=15 MODES=12 CHANTYPES=# PREFIX=(qaohv)~&@%+ CHANMODES=beI,kfL,lj,psmntirRcOAQKVCuzNSMTGZ NETWORK=Network CASEMAPPING=ascii EXTBAN=~,qjncrRa ELIST=MNUCT
```

I have cleaned up the rest of the packet to this point, so this line is exactly what I am working with, though it may have other fields not shown in my example. I have strings that are all named after each of the possible fields that can be in this packet. I wish to set each of the strings, ints and bools to each of the resulting information, sorted by regex groups in C#

To be more clear,

- My `public int maxtargets` would be set to the result of regex group
  `<maxtargets>`
- My `public bool wallchops` would be set to true, if
  the regex group `<wallchops>` returns itself.
- My `public string chantypes` would be set to the result of regex group `<chantypes>`

I am having trouble assembling the regex search string that searches and matches a field and value, in the situations that a field may not exist, and the fields may be in a completely different order.

I hope I am being clear with this and will fill in any blanks I have forgotten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A friend helped me with this finally and we worked out how to successfully match my above string, weather it has a field or not and no matter that order it may be in.

```
(?:(?:SILENCE=(?<silence>\d+)\s?)|(?:MODES=(?<modes>\d+)\s?)|(?:CHANTYPES=(?<chantypes>\S+)\s?)|(?:PREFIX=(?<prefix>\S+)\s?)|(?:MAXTARGETS=(?<maxtargets>\d+)\s?)|(?:WATCH=(?<watch>\d+)\s?)|(?<wallchops>WALLCHOPS)|(?:NETWORK=(?<network>\w+)\s?)|(?:CASEMAPPING=(?<casemapping>\w+)\s?)|(?:CHANMODES=(?<chanmodes>\S+)\s?)|(?:EXTBAN=(?<extban>\S+)\s?)|(?:ELIST=(?<elist>\w+)\s?)|(?:WATCHOPTS=(?<watchopts>\S+)\s?)\s?)
```

Yes, I realize this is a huge Regex Search string and it will return the lines as groups as I wanted. I also realize this isn't the best idea in practice. This search line would grow to massive size and can, and probably would create a vast amount of overhead and wasted CPU time to execute.

SJ,
I thank you greatly for your feedback, I will put your suggested code to use and get this working in that manner, with some minor changes of course.

Answer (score 0):

> in the situations that a field may not exist, and the fields may be in a completely different order.

I thought writing a REGEX to the above mentioned case is not a best practice. Instead, you could use simple string methods to achieve your goal.

```
class IrcParser
{
    private string input;

    public IrcParser(string input)
    {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public Irc GetResult()
    {
        Irc irc = new Irc();
        string[] result = input.Split();
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] FieldValue = result[i].Split('=');
            switch (FieldValue[0])
             {
                case "MAXTARGETS":
                     irc.maxTargets = Convert.ToInt32(FieldValue[1]);
                     break;
                case "WALLCHOPS":
                     irc.wallChops = true;
                     break;
                case "CHANTYPES":
                    irc.chanTypes = FieldValue[1];
                    break;
            }
        }
        return irc;
    } 

    public Irc GetResultByRegex()
    {
        Irc irc = new Irc();
        MatchMaxTargets(ref irc.maxTargets);
        MatchWallChops(ref irc.wallChops);
        MatchChanTypes(ref irc.chanTypes);
        return irc;
    }

    private void MatchMaxTargets(ref int maxTargets)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=MAXTARGETS=)(\d+)");
        Match m = regex.Match(input);
        if (m.Success){
            maxTargets = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[1].Value);
        }
    }

    private void MatchWallChops(ref bool wallChops)
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(input, "WALLCHOPS"))
        {
            wallChops = true;
        }
    }

    private void MatchChanTypes(ref string chanTypes)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=CHANTYPES=)(.*?)(?=\s)");
        Match m = regex.Match(input);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            chanTypes = m.Groups[1].Value;
        }
    }

}

class Irc
{
    public int maxTargets;
    public bool wallChops;
    public string chanTypes;
}
```

Updated:
I added methods to perform REGEX match on individual field values. If we write a single line REGEX, the group result order will change based on fields availability.(In that situation, you can't assign a group value to appropriate fields.)

Hope it helps you.
--SJ

Comment: While I agree that there are probably far better ways of doing this, however I am looking for a regex string to return this. I am trying to learn regex and why this would or wouldn't be the best practice for what I am trying to accomplish. I want to make my own mistakes with code and learn from them and improve the outcome in the end. I will certainly take your string methods and see I can do in this regard.

But, I ultimately need a Regex for my problem.

Comment: We can't write a single line Regex pattern to your case. Becasue, your field values may or mat not be presented in a given string. I updated my answer.